# Creating a program that creates a full screen overlay

Tags: c++, windows, opengl

I want to write a program that would create a transparent overlay filling the entire screen in Windows 7, preferably with C++ and OpenGL. Though, if there is an API written in another language that makes this super easy, I would be more than willing to use that too. In general, I assume I would have to be able to read the pixels that are already on the screen somehow.

Using the same method screen capture software uses to get the pixels from the screen and then redrawing them would work initially, but the problem would then be if the screen updates. My program would then have to minimize/close and reappear in order for me to be able to read the underlying pixels.

Comment: If you only make your window transparent, Windows itself will make sure that the windows below it will draw themselves first, making screen capture redundant. Have you investigated transparency in Windows? Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: Hi Christian - I'm wondering how you solved this challenge in the end? Would love to learn from your experience!

Answer (score 2):

Windows Vista introduced a new flag into the PIXELFORMATDESCRIPTOR: PFD_SUPPORT_COMPOSITION. If the OpenGL context is created with an alpha channel, i.e. AlphaBits of the PFD is nonzero, the alpha channel of the OpenGL framebuffer is respected by the Windows compositor.

Then by creating a full screen, borderless, undecorated window you get this exakt kind of overlay you desire. However this window will still receive all input events, so you'll have to do some grunt work and pass on all input events to the underlying windows manually.